# Binding WPF not executed immediately

Tags: wpf

I would like to update busy indicator on the beginning of the function.
The binding executed only when function is done.

```
private async void DoJob()
{
    await Task.Run(() => SetBusyIndicatorState(true));

    var res = await ( LongFunction());
    ...

    await Task.Run(() => SetBusyIndicatorState(false));
}

private void SetBusyIndicatorState(bool state )
{
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            RadBusyIndicatorLoad.IsBusy = state;
        }));
}
```

Comment: When I execute the function I don't see busy indicator because the binding executing on the end (await Task.Run(() => SetBusyIndicatorState(false));)

Answer (score 0):

Mark your method async and await for the execution complete.

```
      SetBusyIndicatorState(true);

  Task.Run(() =>
  {
      //implement
  }).ContinueWith(completedtaskresult=>
  {
      SetBusyIndicatorState(false)
  }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I can not because I receive message(The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it). Inside of the LongFunction() I run other Task